# Gtk-WARNING Locale not supported by C library

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I was trying to install a package after add some languages to my system and it's seems like impossible. I tried to fix it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` that helped me when my terminal prompt wasn't opening but it looks like it doesn't fix all the problems.

The complete error is this:

```
(mintSources.py:5884): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:00:48.932: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1689, in <module>
    add_repository_via_cli(ppa_line, codename, options.forceYes, use_ppas)
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 141, in add_repository_via_cli
    print(_("You are about to add the following PPA:"))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe5' in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And when I write `locale` the answer is this one:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=nb_no.utf8
LANGUAGE=nb_NO
LC_CTYPE="nb_no.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="nb_no.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="nb_no.utf8"
LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_AR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I've three languages installed, seems like Norwegian is the one who's working strange 
`ls -lah`

```
    total 24K
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb  4 00:49 <font color="#729FCF"><b>.</b></font>

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Dec 17 10:26 <font color="#729FCF"><b>..</b></font>
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  294 Jul 17  2018 en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  372 Jul 17  2018 es
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  780 Feb  4 00:40 mintlocale
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   24 Feb  5 06:48 nb
```